# No matching version found for @babel/helper-validator-identifier@^7.9.5

Tags: angular, dependencies, babeljs, npm-install

I had run npm install to install angular dependencies. While installing i'm facing issues with babel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try uninstalling angular/cli and installing again:
Do the same to babel package, try to uninstall it and install again.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
```

Check if you followed this steps in babel installation:

```
npm init
npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-typescript @babel/preset-env
```

Remember to check your package.json file in order to see if dependecies have been installed correctly with latest version !

If this doesn't work, please paste your code here with error in order to see better! :)

Comment: Cleaning up node_modules seems the right solution, that's a weird bug.