# Error after npm install Could not resolve dependency

Tags: angular, npm

After do a git clone im getting this error with my project after `npm install`:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: app-frontend@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: zone.js@0.10.2
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   zone.js@"0.10.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"10.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"10.0.0" from @angular/animations@10.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"10.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\..\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\..\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-19T20_20_14_157Z-debug.log
```

This is my complete package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "app-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "dev": "ng serve -c dev --watch=false",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "10.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "10.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "10.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.14.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "5.2.1",
    "@maestro-ng/core": "https://nexus.org.br/repository/npm-all/@maestro-ng/core/-/core-1.10.0.tgz",
    "@maestro-ng/primeng": "https://nexus.org/repository/npm-all/@maestro-ng/primeng/-/primeng-1.10.0.tgz",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "0.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "chart.js": "2.7.2",
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "g": "2.0.1",
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "js-base64": "2.4.3",
    "moment": "2.27.0",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "9.0.2",
    "ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "5.0.7",
    "ngx-moment": "5.0.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "1.10.88",
    "popper.js": "1.14.4",
    "primeflex": "2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "4.0.0",
    "primeng": "9.1.3",
    "quill": "1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "6.6.2",
    "simple-pdf-viewer": "2.0.3",
    "tslib": "2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1000.5",
    "@angular/cli": "10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "10.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.8.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.0",
    "karma": "5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.10.2",
    "tslint": "6.1.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "5.4.0",
    "typescript": "3.9.7"
  }
}
```

I don't have sure if its a problem with my local, or its a problem with master branch, because i just have cloned the project after delete them.
Im trying to prepare the project to update to angular 12
How i can solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the errors i start to update some packages and put the "^" symbol

```
    {
  "name": "codex-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "dev": "ng serve -c dev --watch=false",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.14.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "5.2.1",
    "@maestro-ng/core": "https://nexus.org.br/repository/npm-all/@maestro-ng/core/-/core-1.10.0.tgz",
    "@maestro-ng/primeng": "https://nexus.org.br/repository/npm-all/@maestro-ng/primeng/-/primeng-1.10.0.tgz",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "0.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "chart.js": "2.7.2",
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "g": "2.0.1",
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "js-base64": "2.4.3",
    "moment": "2.27.0",
    "ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-moment": "5.0.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "1.10.88",
    "popper.js": "1.14.4",
    "primeflex": "2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "4.0.0",
    "primeng": "^10.0.3",
    "quill": "1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "6.6.2",
    "simple-pdf-viewer": "2.0.3",
    "tslib": "2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.8",
    "@angular/cli": "10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "10.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.8.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.0",
    "karma": "5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.10.2",
    "tslint": "^5.4.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
    "typescript": "3.9.7"
  }
}
```

until its solve. I needed to uninstall the angular too, like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61102214/no-matching-version-found-for-babel-helper-validator-identifier7-9-5)
Thanks

Comment: You are still running angular 10 and not 12. If you think you have upgraded to 12 you are mistaken and it can cause bugs later in your project... Uninstall everything related to Angular and install again the right version, it will save you headache in the future

Comment: Maybe i was not clear on the question.What im doing at that time is to migrate an Angular version to the most recent. Thats why i have to solve issues on version 10 and then migrate to 11 and so on.

Comment: Long time no see! Hope you managed to solve this issue all good :)

Comment: Definitely! Thank you by the way!

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see from your package file, no updates to Angular 12 happened. You are still running angular 10. In my experience the issue can be due to a mix of mis-configuration locally within the project. My best guess would be to reinstall the correct version of angular. You can follow this guide that could help you: https://update.angular.io/